# JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application:how can i include javafx runtime in the executable jar file: maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I am working on a JavaFx project using maven on Intellij community. I am facing error 'JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application' on  javafx executable jar but on Intellij everything is ok. How can I resolve this issue. How can I make sure javafx runtime is included in the executable jar file when using maven

I tried:

1. adding  java fx sdk jars in lib folder to my project
2. adding  java fx sdk jars in bin folder to my project